# AS3 LocalConnection Errors

Tags: actionscript-3, localconnection

Not sure where I'm going wrong, for now just trying this out locally. Thanks.

sendingLC.swf does return, LocalConnection.send() succeeded

This is the errors I get from Flash.
Error #2044: Unhandled AsyncErrorEvent:. text=Error #2095: flash.net.LocalConnection was unable to invoke callback myMethod. error=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property myMethod not found on flash.net.LocalConnection and there is no default value.

Code for sendingLC.swf:

```
import flash.net.LocalConnection

var sendingLC:LocalConnection;
sendingLC = new LocalConnection();
sendingLC.allowDomain('*');
Security.allowDomain("*");
sendBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sendIt);

function sendIt(eventObj:MouseEvent):void {
    sendingLC.send('myConnection', 'myMethod');
}

sendingLC.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandler);


function statusHandler (event:StatusEvent):void
{
    switch (event.level)
    {
        case "status" :
            textArea.text = ("LocalConnection.send() succeeded");
            break;
        case "error" :
            textArea.text = ("LocalConnection.send() failed");
            break;
    }
}
```

Code for receivingLC.swf:

```
import flash.net.LocalConnection

var receivingLC:LocalConnection;
receivingLC = new LocalConnection();
receivingLC.allowDomain('*');
Security.allowDomain("*");
receivingLC.connect('myConnection');

function myMethod():void {trace('Hello World')}
```

Comment: At what point are you calling the sendIt function? Are both swf's loaded at that time?

Comment: I open up both swf's, and then click on sendBtn, which calls sendIt

Comment: Are they opened in a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be an issue with making the connection in the receiver.

```
try {
  var receivingLC:LocalConnection;
  receivingLC = new LocalConnection();
  receivingLC.allowDomain('*');
  Security.allowDomain("*"); // not sure this line is needed
  receivingLC.connect('myConnection');
} catch (error:ArgumentError) {
  trace('failure to make connection ' + error.toString() );
}
```

Also something to note do not test LocalConnections in the flash api do it through a browser when you are first making these as permission issues can be a cranky woman.

Comment: So I finally just had some time to try out what you had suggested, I am now testing within a browser, in the final implementation each swf will be inside seperate iFrames, so that is how I'm testing. I still get the same errors as when I was testing locally, with no additional output. Thanks

Comment: try sendingLC.send('_myConnection', 'myMethod');  and receivingLC.connect('_myConnection');

Comment: The underscore does have a meaning

Answer (score 2):

I also had issues with the LocalConnection giving me callback errors, but it stopped when I added the client property to the connection. Then it started working, even in flash IDE.

```
var conn:LocalConnection;
conn = new LocalConnection();
conn.allowDomain('*');
conn.client = this;
conn.connect('localThingieConnector');
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try making `myMethod` public like so:

```
public function myMethod():void{
  trace("hello world");
}
```

Also you should try/catch the send call so you get more information about errors like so:

```
try{
  sendingLC.send('myConnection', 'myMethod');
}
catch(e:Error){
  trace(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: I tried try/catch as you have it, but I get 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Exception. I've not used try/catch before so I'll have to look into it more. Thanks